# Bind gridview when column not exists in datatable but binding at itemtemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having a `dataset` which i am pivoting and then binding to a grid view. It is working fine when all the `itemtemplates` value are present in the pivoted table but in case if any of the column is not present in the pivoted table, then at the time of binding the gridview , i am getting error . Please help me that how i will handle it in grid view if any of the columns is not present but i am binding it to grid view `itemtemplate`. Below is my grid view code.

```
                    <asp:GridView ID="gvCoreUtilization" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#cEcFcE"
                    BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" OnRowCreated="grdPivot3_RowCreated"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="grdCoreUtilization_RowDataBound">
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" />
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblRoleID" Text='<%#Eval("RoleId") %>' runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                SupervisorName
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblSupervisorName" Text='<%#Eval("SupervisorName") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                UserECode
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblUserECode" Text='<%#Eval("UserECode") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                UserName
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblUserName" Text='<%#Eval("UserName") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                Designation
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblDesignation" Text='<%#Eval("Designation") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                L & D Training%
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblLDTraining" Text='<%#Eval("L & D Training%") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                Non Production%
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblNonProduction" Text='<%#Eval("Non Production%") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                Process Support%
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblProcessSupport" Text='<%#Eval("Process Support%") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                Process Training%
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblProcessTraining" Text='<%#Eval("Process Training%") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                Production%
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblProduction" Text='<%#Eval("Production%") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                System Downtime%
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblSystemDowntime" Text='<%#Eval("System Downtime%") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                Grand Total%
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblGrandTotal" Text='<%#Eval("Grand Total%") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

Actually `"L & D Training%"`,`"Non Production%"`,`"Process Support%`",`"Process Training%"`,`"Production%"`,`"System Downtime%"`,`"Grand Total%"` are the pivoted columns which i am binding to itemtemplate .For some User few of these column are not present and while binding the grid i am getting error.

Below is the code of my Pivot class where i am doing pivot :-

```
private DataTable _SourceTable = new DataTable();
    private IEnumerable<DataRow> _Source = new List<DataRow>();

    public Pivot(DataTable SourceTable)
    {
        _SourceTable = SourceTable;
        _Source = SourceTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>();
    }

    public DataTable PivotData(string DataField, AggregateFunction Aggregate, string[] RowFields, string[] ColumnFields)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string Separator = ".";
        var RowList = _SourceTable.DefaultView.ToTable(true, RowFields).AsEnumerable().ToList();
        for (int index = RowFields.Count() - 1; index >= 0; index--)
            RowList = RowList.OrderBy(x => x.Field<object>(RowFields[index])).ToList();
        // Gets the list of columns .(dot) separated.
        var ColList = (from x in _SourceTable.AsEnumerable()
                       select new
                       {
                           Name = ColumnFields.Select(n => x.Field<object>(n))
                               .Aggregate((a, b) => a += Separator + b.ToString())
                       })
                           .Distinct()
                           .OrderBy(m => m.Name);

        //dt.Columns.Add(RowFields);
        foreach (string s in RowFields)
            dt.Columns.Add(s);

        foreach (var col in ColList)
            dt.Columns.Add(col.Name.ToString());  // Cretes the result columns.//

        foreach (var RowName in RowList)
        {
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            string strFilter = string.Empty;

            foreach (string Field in RowFields)
            {
                row[Field] = RowName[Field];
                strFilter += " and " + Field + " = '" + RowName[Field].ToString() + "'";
            }
            strFilter = strFilter.Substring(5);

            foreach (var col in ColList)
            {
                string filter = strFilter;
                string[] strColValues = col.Name.ToString().Split(Separator.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.None);
                for (int i = 0; i < ColumnFields.Length; i++)
                    filter += " and " + ColumnFields[i] + " = '" + strColValues[i] + "'";
                row[col.Name.ToString()] = GetData(filter, DataField, Aggregate);
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        return dt;
    }

    public DataTable PivotAllocationData(string DataField, AggregateFunction Aggregate, string[] RowFields, string[] ColumnFields)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string Separator = ".";
        var RowList = _SourceTable.DefaultView.ToTable(true, RowFields).AsEnumerable().ToList();
        for (int index = RowFields.Count() - 1; index >= 0; index--)
            RowList = RowList.OrderBy(x => x.Field<object>(RowFields[index])).ToList();
        // Gets the list of columns .(dot) separated.
        var ColList = (from x in _SourceTable.AsEnumerable()
                       select new
                       {
                           Name = ColumnFields.Select(n => x.Field<object>(n))
                               .Aggregate((a, b) => a += Separator + b.ToString())
                       })
                           .Distinct()
                           .OrderBy(m => m.Name);

        //dt.Columns.Add(RowFields);
        foreach (string s in RowFields)
            dt.Columns.Add(s);

        foreach (var col in ColList)
            dt.Columns.Add(col.Name.ToString());  // Cretes the result columns.//

        foreach (var RowName in RowList)
        {
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            string strFilter = string.Empty;

            foreach (string Field in RowFields)
            {
                row[Field] = RowName[Field];
                strFilter += " and " + Field + " = '" + RowName[Field].ToString() + "'";
            }
            strFilter = strFilter.Substring(5);

            foreach (var col in ColList)
            {
                string filter = strFilter;
                string[] strColValues = col.Name.ToString().Split(Separator.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.None);
                for (int i = 0; i < ColumnFields.Length; i++)
                    filter += " and " + ColumnFields[i] + " = '" + strColValues[i] + "'";
                row[col.Name.ToString()] = GetAllocationData(filter, DataField, Aggregate);
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        return dt;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Retrives the data for matching RowField value and ColumnFields values with Aggregate function applied on them.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Filter">DataTable Filter condition as a string</param>
    /// <param name="DataField">The column name which needs to spread out in Data Part of the Pivoted table</param>
    /// <param name="Aggregate">Enumeration to determine which function to apply to aggregate the data</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private object GetData(string Filter, string DataField, AggregateFunction Aggregate)
    {
        try
        {
            DataRow[] FilteredRows = _SourceTable.Select(Filter);
            object[] objList = FilteredRows.Select(x => x.Field<object>(DataField)).ToArray();

            switch (Aggregate)
            {
                case AggregateFunction.Average:
                    return GetAverage(objList);
                case AggregateFunction.Count:
                    return objList.Count();
                case AggregateFunction.Exists:
                    return (objList.Count() == 0) ? "False" : "True";
                case AggregateFunction.First:
                    return GetFirst(objList);
                case AggregateFunction.Last:
                    return GetLast(objList);
                case AggregateFunction.Max:
                    return GetMax(objList);
                case AggregateFunction.Min:
                    return GetMin(objList);
                case AggregateFunction.Sum:
                    return GetSum(objList);
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "#Error";
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrives the data for matching RowField value and ColumnFields values with Aggregate function applied on them.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Filter">DataTable Filter condition as a string</param>
    /// <param name="DataField">The column name which needs to spread out in Data Part of the Pivoted table</param>
    /// <param name="Aggregate">Enumeration to determine which function to apply to aggregate the data</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private object GetAllocationData(string Filter, string DataField, AggregateFunction Aggregate)
    {
        try
        {
            DataRow[] FilteredRows = _SourceTable.Select(Filter);
            object[] objList = FilteredRows.Select(x => x.Field<object>(DataField)).ToArray();

            switch (Aggregate)
            {
                case AggregateFunction.Average:
                    return GetAverage(objList);
                case AggregateFunction.Count:
                    return objList.Count();
                case AggregateFunction.Exists:
                    return (objList.Count() == 0) ? "False" : "True";
                case AggregateFunction.First:
                    return GetFirst(objList);
                case AggregateFunction.Last:
                    return GetLast(objList);
                case AggregateFunction.Max:
                    return GetMax(objList);
                case AggregateFunction.Min:
                    return GetMin(objList);
                case AggregateFunction.Sum:
                    return GetAllocationSum(objList);
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "#Error";
        }
    }

    private object GetAverage(object[] objList)
    {
        return objList.Count() == 0 ? null : (object)(Convert.ToDecimal(GetSum(objList)) / objList.Count());
    }
    private object GetSum(object[] objList)
    {
        return objList.Count() == 0 ? null : (object)(objList.Aggregate(new decimal(), (x, y) => x += Convert.ToDecimal(y)) + "%");
    }
    private object GetAllocationSum(object[] objList)
    {
        return objList.Count() == 0 ? null : (object)(objList.Aggregate(new decimal(), (x, y) => x += Convert.ToDecimal(y)));
    }
    private object GetFirst(object[] objList)
    {
        return (objList.Count() == 0) ? null : objList.First();
    }
    private object GetLast(object[] objList)
    {
        return (objList.Count() == 0) ? null : objList.Last();
    }
    private object GetMax(object[] objList)
    {
        return (objList.Count() == 0) ? null : objList.Max();
    }
    private object GetMin(object[] objList)
    {
        return (objList.Count() == 0) ? null : objList.Min();
    }


public enum AggregateFunction
```

{
    Count = 1,
    Sum = 2,
    First = 3,
    Last = 4,
    Average = 5,
    Max = 6,
    Min = 7,
    Exists = 8
}

Comment: are there any primary key which will be present in every scenario?

Comment: No, Actually "L & D Training%","Non Production%","Process Support%","Process Training%","Production%","System Downtime%","Grand Total%" are the pivoted columns which i am binding to itemtemplate .For some User few of these column are not present and while binding the grid i am getting error.\

Comment: In your database query just try `ifnull(columnname,'') as abc` here column name is your table column name and '' is basically assign this column to default value if it return null and abc is alias name of column.hope you understand ,,just try...

Comment: this mean your data is in excel file?? If yes then how you are querying it? using oledb or something else? Please provide the full detail as the actual implementation will depend on the actual datbase layer being used.

Comment: Updated my question and provided code which ia m using to make my datatable in pivot .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the actual database being used has been not provided by you. You can apply the following trick. 
The thing is that you will nedd to create a wrapper class for extracting the what ever data you have then formating the data in well defined schema that is being used by your grid.

Eg. Suppose you have 3 column in a table but another can contain <>3 and so on. Since your gridview appearence is same, create a datatable containing all rows of the gridview.
create a function that extract all the data and fill this datatable with the data available and the data that is not available will be filled by null or blank values.

This way you can mitigate the problem of exception being throws. The actual implementation of the function converting variable length table to fixed length datatable will depend on the actual logic used for creating those varaible length datatable and how they are mapped to each other.